# How to fix the version update the target version is change to 28

Tags: android, android-version

When I upload the app in the play store its throws an error to change the target version to 28 if I changed I got a lot of error.So anyone helps me to solve this problem. I tried but nothing is working for me.

I changed all the libraries to updated version but in my code, I am data binding I am getting a lot of errors in data binding generated class I shared the Gradle file.

I expect the correct solution to solve  this issue

Comment: Post your error log and `build.gradle` file in the question

Comment: Just do this ->Android Studio -> Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX.

Now change the target version to 28 in gradle files in click on sync options

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion.
BuildTools should be targeting targetSdkVersion
e.g:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
```

and you should match the **com.android.support** implementations to the buildToolsVersion

Comment: I am already trying this solution is not working, please give any other solution for this problem

Comment: does it build locally?

Comment: yes, its build locally but when I run the app I got an error like this.                              org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Comment: could you run the gradle build and run the app afterwards? Please post the StackTrace / Errorlog

Comment: error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceIdService I got this error please advise me to solve this

Comment: please look at this article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService - you will need to use a newer implementation

Comment: please give any example about the link

Comment: it states, that your FirebaseInstanceIdService  is deprecated and soon to be removed. So, go with the newer implementation

Comment: I got another issue like 
Inconvertible type:cannot cast android.fragment.app.Fragment to com.google.android.gms.map.SupportMapFragment how can I solve this issue please advise me

Comment: without code, this is difficult, but you try to cast a false types

Answer (score 1):

> When I upload the app in the play store its throws an error to change the target version to 28 if I changed I got a lot of error.

This is because the minimum requirement for Google play is api 28, see [Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). Here the excerpt:

> When you upload an APK, it needs to meet Google Play’s target API level requirements. Starting August 1, 2019, Google Play requires that new apps target at least Android 9.0 (API level 28), and that app updates target Android 9.0 from November 1, 2019. Until these dates, new apps and app updates must target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26).

Hence, the Play Store is rejecting your application if target version is < 28.

> I changed all the libraries to updated version but in my code, I am data binding I am getting a lot of errors in data binding generated class I shared the Gradle file.

You need to make sure that `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support libraries` dependencies use the same version. So, make sure your `build.gradle` something like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
      ...
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 28

      ...
    }
}


dependencies {

   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0'

   ...
}
```

Comment: I am already trying this one is not working

Comment: Please Post your error log and `build.gradle` to question then.